# Beaglebone folder location

Tags: beagleboneblack

How can I change the contents of the DOS folder that pops up on my computer, Debian Stretch 9.4, when I plug in the USB cable to the Beaglebone Black Rev C? In older versions, it was located in a DOS partition but I do not see that anymore.

Comment: Welcome! We will probably need more details so you have a better chance of getting this question answered. What version of Stretch are you using? Does the beaglebone have a firmware? If so, what version? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you I have updated the question with the information you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys I found it. The files are located in the Linux partition files on the eMMC at /var/cache/doc-beaglebone-getting started/beaglebone-getting started-(date code).img Actually there are several folders here one for each type of board that the software maybe loaded on.